# CSS - Horizontally split page in two halves without overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to split my html page in two halves (60% top half, and 40% bottom half) However, to my surprise, I am having a hard time doing so without having my content overlap when the browser window resize. I tried flex, absolute positioning, percentages...

What I have is this

**HTML**

```
   <div class="top">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   </div>

   <div class="bottom">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
.container {
   height:100%;
}
.top {
   height:60%;
   background:red;
}
.bottom {
   height:40%;
   background:yellow;
}
```

This works well.

[image]

However, when the page is resized, the top part overlaps the bottom part.

[image]

How can I make it so the two halves are aware of content height and not overlap? I don't want to set height in pixels. I am open to JavaScript only if there is absolutely no solution with CSS only

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8tvn0kw6/1/)

Comment: how u want it to behave.. should they scroll instead https://jsfiddle.net/8tvn0kw6/3/

Comment: No! I don't want to individual scrollbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `min-height`to avoid overlap

```
.top {
  min-height:60%;
  background:red;
}
.bottom {
  min-height:40%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: THAT'S IT :) I cant believe I did not try min-height. This works exactly like I needed! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

if you reduce the space, the content needs to go somewhere. you have 2 options:
1. hide the content(overflow:hidden)
2. show a scrollbar.(overflow:scroll)
i think it's best if you put a vertical scrollbar on body with `overflow-y:auto` so when you resize the page, the scroller appears automatically.

Comment: I understand the content needs to go somewhere. I don't want the divs to overlap. I want it so that when the two divs do not have more space to stop resizing and just show a body scrollbar.

Comment: that's what i suggested. give me a minute. let me give you a fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
   height:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
.container {
   height:100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
   flex: 6;
   background:red;
   width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
   flex: 4;
   background:yellow;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
 <div class="top">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   </div>

   <div class="bottom">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ca9wqdc6/1/)

Comment: When I opened your example in the Full Page and resized the window really small, it made a scroll bar, but it wasn't able to show the top text.  Resizing the window pushed the top text up, and when you scrolled to the top, it was still not visible.

Comment: Same here. I had the same problem when I tried with Flex. It ignores the content at the top and hides it. However, the bottom div seems to behave ok. I just wish the top div did the same

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto` to your CSS.  Since your `div.top` is too short to hold all the text, it spills out of the element and onto `div.bottom`.  When you apply the `overflow` property to your elements, it keeps the text within the bounds of the elements and triggers scrollbars when the content becomes too long to fit in the view.

```
.top,.bottom {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: However, this will give me two separate scrollbars. I don't want that! I want it so when the page is resized, the divs should not overlap and just get the main body scrollbar.

Comment: If you want to do that, you'd use `overflow: hidden` instead, but then any hidden content would never be able to be seen.  The main body scrollbar would not help you since the two `div`s are in full view.  You'd need scroll bars for the `div`s themselves.

Answer (score 0):

**`Remove height then height will adjust according to text`**

https://jsfiddle.net/8tvn0kw6/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your html & css is fine, and you have two options here to fix the problem you are facing:

- use `overflow: hidden` - this way content wan't overlap because content drawn outside of parent boundaries will be hidden
- use `min-height: 200px` - this way you define the minimum height your top element must always have and your bottom element will be shifted

[Here's jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/7emug3a0/)